# How can I avoid saturation in current source amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, pwm, current-source, feedback, class-d

I'm designing a class d amplifier with current feedback as in figure below
[image]

with the following features:

- Vbus=50V
- Iout programmable from 100mA to 1A rms
- Vout=35Vrms max

When the load overcomes the programmed current (i.e. 1Arms) the amplifier saturates and the sinusoidal output becomes a square wave output. For example i want to transmit on 1200 ohm a 35Vrms sinusoidal voltage even though the current feedback is not locked.

So my purpose is to mantain a maximum allowable voltage on the output.

Is it possible to obtain that feature? A second feedback is needed?

Comment: all variables need to be defined in terms of transfer function for current,  voltage, impedance so that linear range can be controlled and phase margin of loop can be improved with compensation for different load ranges.

Comment: You have a variable voltage source connected to the inverted input of the first amplifier. The voltage at the inverted pin is determined solely by Vsin, therefore there is zero negative feedback. It is to be expected that the amplifier to swing from saturation to saturation. Perhaps connecting Vsin to the "+" pin is closer to what you want.

Comment: The first op-amp stage does not appear to be doing anything sensible. Can you explain it further? Also, which sinusoidal output becomes square? What do you mean by "locked"?

Comment: @rioraxe And a resistor to ground on the inverted input.

Comment: Applying a feedback loop if the transconductance is already limited to what you want to get on the output, makes little sense, as there is no 'excess' open loop gain.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to be "how do I set a maximum allowable voltage on the output".

In a class D, the maximum output voltage is determined by the voltage on the output stage. To ensure the output voltage never exceeds 35Vrms, set the voltage of the output stage to a maximum of 99V. That way, regardless of the input signal the output switching elements will only be able to generate an oscillating wave with a maximum of 35Vrms.

Answer (score 0):

You need either a voltage feedback path, or to design your hard limits within the PWM section (which will probably involve some sort of feedback).  With just the current feedback the amplifier has no way of "knowing" what the output voltage is.

Why are you using current feedback?